# Document on cloning is not correct?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, clone

I'm viewing VMWare vSphere Client [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50/GUID-5C504B67-CDB3-42FC-8B3B-737201A725DD.html) and it tells to right click the virtual machine and hit `clone`

[image]

but I cannot find that in VMWare vSphere Client

[image]

What's wrong here everyone?

ps

I'm using version 5.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be directly connected to the ESXi host.

From your first image:

[image]

Comment: THAT my friend was one SPECTACULAR way to answer.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I hadn't had good occasion for hand-drawn circles in a while!  It looks pretty weak compared to the nice, clean ones in the question :)

Comment: @ShaneMadden I use Screenpresso which is free and super cool to use

Comment: @ShaneMadden I really don't get what `direct connected to vCenter Server`, please explain more.

Comment: @NamG.VU In order for the clone functionality to be available, you must be managing your ESXi host with a vCenter server, and you must be logged in with the vSphere client to the vCenter server - in your screenshot above, it appears that you've connected with your vSphere client directly to your ESXi host.  That's causing the clone option to be unavailable.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Pls update this to your anser so as to be accepted

Comment: @NamG.VU What updating do you think it needs?